# Google tag manager tags some of them fired and some are not in GA

Tags: google-tag-manager

I got a weird problem of my tags in GTM

The tag are fired in my website but some are appear in event section of GA and some are not

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that there's a problem with your triggers that's causing the tags to not fire. Also possible is that you haven't published the latest version of your container, or that the tags are firing to the wrong Google Analytics account.

It would help if you could give a little more detail: have you tested the tags in Google Tag Manager's debugger?